# Mysql issue pertaining to syntax error on Not IN

Tags: mysql

```
select tf.Id,tf.Name,tf.LName,tf.Rank,tf.Category
where tf.Id not in (select fighter_id from tbl_player_fighter where league_id=91)
and  tf.Status ='1'
```

This is throwing a syntax error. Any advice on how to fix this.  Thanks.

Comment: tip: in the future, post the actual error message as well. It makes it MUCH easier to spot the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a FROM clause, so it doesn't know the main table to use.